# Como montar um visualizador de quadrinhos online?

Tags: mysql, imagem, slideshow

Boa noite pessoal!
Eu sempre trabalhei com frontend e muito pouco com php e mysql, mas decidi fazer meu site pessoal de quadrinhos.
Uma imagem da minha página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Cada imagem é um link de material no banco de dados.Ao clicar nos quadrinhos correspondentes a HQs, a pessoa vai para uma página de leitura online das páginas e aí está minha dificuldade.
Eu queria criar algo parecido com essa página: https://hqbr.com.br/hqs/The%20Walking%20Dead/capitulo/1/leitor/0#1 , mas eu não estou sabendo fazer os comandos de passar páginas.
Como eu faço o comando de passar para próxima ou voltar uma página e ao mesmo tempo manter uma combo box para a pessoa escolher para qual página avançar?
No meu BD, as páginas vem de uma tabela com os campos *obra, nome do volume, páginas totais, pagina # e data de publicação*.
Obrigado qualquer toque. Só falta essas páginas dinâmicas de conteúdo pra eu terminar.

Comment: Se você é front-end por que usar php e mysql? Acredito que seria melhor pra você fazer algo com javascript e no-sql

Comment: Meu negócio é mais html+css. Eu pensei que a maneira mais prática para visualizar minhas revistas assim que eu fosse publicando seria php e mysql. Como eu faria isso em javascript?

Comment: Tem algumas formas, uma simples e segura e que uso, é usar o firebase, ele possui um banco de dados em tempo real onde pode guardar os links, datas etc em formato json. Se quiser também pode usar o storage para guardar os arquivos

Comment: Dei uma olhada. Interessante. Valeu a dica, Guilherme. Vou ver se resolvo isso adaptando um slideshow q tenho aqui. Valeu!